# ChartJS Donut Chart not being displayed

Tags: javascript, html, chart.js

I am trying to display a simple ChartJS donut chart in a .php file, The HTML Card is being displayed but not the chart. The same code works when used in a local .html file, the page header for the .php file is stored in a separate file and I am unsure if this is the reason why this isn't working

HTML for Donut Chart:

```html
<div class="card card-danger">
            <div class="card-header">
              <h3 class="card-title">Donut Chart</h3>

              <div class="card-tools">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-tool" data-card-widget="collapse">
                  <i class="fas fa-minus"></i>
                </button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-tool" data-card-widget="remove">
                  <i class="fas fa-times"></i>
                </button>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="card-body">
              <canvas id="donutChart" style="min-height: 250px; height: 250px; max-height: 250px; max-width: 100%;"></canvas>
            </div>
          </div>
```

Javascript:

```html
<!-- jQuery -->
<script src="plugins/jquery/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- Bootstrap 4 -->
<script src="plugins/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
<!-- ChartJS -->
<script src="plugins/chart.js/Chart.min.js"></script>
<!-- AdminLTE App -->
<script src="dist/js/adminlte.min.js"></script>
<!-- AdminLTE for demo purposes -->
<script src="dist/js/demo.js"></script>
<!-- Page specific script -->
<script>

  $(function () {
    /* ChartJS
     * -------
     * Here we will create a few charts using ChartJS
     */

    //-------------
    //- DONUT CHART -
    //-------------
    // Get context with jQuery - using jQuery's .get() method.
    var donutChartCanvas = $('#donutChart').get(0).getContext('2d')
    var donutData = {
      labels: [
        'Chrome',
        'IE',
        'FireFox',
        'Safari',
        'Opera',
        'Navigator'
      ],
      datasets: [
        {
          data: [700, 500, 400, 600, 300, 100],
          backgroundColor: ['#f56954', '#00a65a', '#f39c12', '#00c0ef', '#3c8dbc', '#d2d6de']
        }
      ]
    }
    var donutOptions = {
      maintainAspectRatio: false,
      responsive: true
    }
    //Create pie or doughnut chart
    // You can switch between pie and doughnut using the method below.
    new Chart(donutChartCanvas, {
      type: 'doughnut',
      data: donutData,
      options: donutOptions
    })

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

All code for file:

```html
<?php
session_start();

if ($_SESSION['email'] == "") {

  header("location:login.php");

}
include_once 'header.php';

?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
</head>

<body>
<!-- Content Wrapper. Contains page content -->
<div class="content-wrapper">
  <!-- Content Header (Page header) -->
  <div class="content-header">
    <div class="container-fluid">
      <div class="row mb-2">
        <div class="col-sm-6">
          <h1 class="m-0">Dashboard</h1>
        </div><!-- /.col -->
        <div class="col-sm-6">
          <ol class="breadcrumb float-sm-right">
            <li class="breadcrumb-item"><a href="index.php">Home</a></li>
            <li class="breadcrumb-item active">Dashboard</li>
          </ol>
        </div><!-- /.col -->
      </div><!-- /.row -->
    </div><!-- /.container-fluid -->
  </div>
  <!-- /.content-header -->

  <!-- Main content -->
  <section class="content">
    <div class="container-fluid">


      <!-- Small boxes (Stat box) -->
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-3 col-6">

          <!-- small box -->
          <div class="small-box bg-info">
            <div class="inner">
              <h3>150</h3>
              <p>New Complaints</p>
            </div>
            <div class="icon">
              <i class="fas fa-plus-square"></i>
            </div>
            <a href="#" class="small-box-footer">Check them out <i class="fas fa-chevron-right"></i></a>
          </div>
        </div>

        <!-- ./col -->
        <div class="col-lg-3 col-6">

          <!-- small box -->
          <div class="small-box bg-success">
            <div class="inner">
              <h3>53<sup style="font-size: 20px"></sup></h3>
              <p>Solved Complaints</p>
            </div>
            <div class="icon">
              <i class="fas fa-check-square"></i>
            </div>
            <a href="#" class="small-box-footer">More info <i class="fas fa-chevron-right"></i></i></a>
          </div>
        </div>

        <!-- ./col -->
        <div class="col-lg-3 col-6">

          <!-- small box -->
          <div class="small-box bg-danger">
            <div class="inner">
              <h3>44</h3>
              <p>Unsolved Complaints</p>
            </div>
            <div class="icon">
              <i class="fas fa-times"></i>
            </div>
            <a href="#" class="small-box-footer">Solve now <i class="fas fa-chevron-right"></i></i></a>
          </div>
        </div>

        <!-- ./col -->
        <div class="col-lg-3 col-6">

          <!-- small box -->
          <div class="small-box bg-warning">
            <div class="inner">
              <h3>65</h3>
              <p>Total Users</p>
            </div>
            <div class="icon">
              <i class="fas fa-user-friends"></i>
            </div>
            <a href="#" class="small-box-footer">More info <i class="fas fa-chevron-right"></i></a>
          </div>
        </div>

        <!-- ./col -->
      </div>
      <!-- /.row -->
      <!-- Main row -->
      <div class="row">
        <!-- Left col -->
        <section class="col-lg-7 connectedSortable">

          <!-- DONUT CHART -->
          <div class="card card-danger">
            <div class="card-header">
              <h3 class="card-title">Donut Chart</h3>

              <div class="card-tools">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-tool" data-card-widget="collapse">
                  <i class="fas fa-minus"></i>
                </button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-tool" data-card-widget="remove">
                  <i class="fas fa-times"></i>
                </button>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="card-body">
              <canvas id="donutChart" style="min-height: 250px; height: 250px; max-height: 250px; max-width: 100%;"></canvas>
            </div>
            <!-- /.card-body -->
          </div>
          <!-- /.card -->
      </div>

  </section>
  <!-- /.Left col -->
  <!-- right col (We are only adding the ID to make the widgets sortable)-->

</div>
<!-- ./col -->

<!-- jQuery -->
<script src="plugins/jquery/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- Bootstrap 4 -->
<script src="plugins/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
<!-- ChartJS -->
<script src="plugins/chart.js/Chart.min.js"></script>
<!-- AdminLTE App -->
<script src="dist/js/adminlte.min.js"></script>
<!-- AdminLTE for demo purposes -->
<script src="dist/js/demo.js"></script>
<!-- Page specific script -->
<script>

  $(function () {
    /* ChartJS
     * -------
     * Here we will create a few charts using ChartJS
     */

    //-------------
    //- DONUT CHART -
    //-------------
    // Get context with jQuery - using jQuery's .get() method.
    var donutChartCanvas = $('#donutChart').get(0).getContext('2d')
    var donutData = {
      labels: [
        'Chrome',
        'IE',
        'FireFox',
        'Safari',
        'Opera',
        'Navigator'
      ],
      datasets: [
        {
          data: [700, 500, 400, 600, 300, 100],
          backgroundColor: ['#f56954', '#00a65a', '#f39c12', '#00c0ef', '#3c8dbc', '#d2d6de']
        }
      ]
    }
    var donutOptions = {
      maintainAspectRatio: false,
      responsive: true
    }
    //Create pie or doughnut chart
    // You can switch between pie and doughnut using the method below.
    new Chart(donutChartCanvas, {
      type: 'doughnut',
      data: donutData,
      options: donutOptions
    })

</script>
</body>
</html>

<?php

include_once 'footer.php';


?>
```

Comment: Have you confirmed that the relative paths to your JavaScript files are correct?

Comment: Yes all paths to the javascript are correct